# Definition of $\operatorname{Lie}(E)$ for an elliptic curve $E$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, schemes, moduli-space

I'm reading Ehlen's *Singular moduli of higher level and special cycles* ([arXiv link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.02711.pdf)) which uses the following definition of an elliptic curve:

> **Definition 1.2**: Let $S$ be a scheme. A proper smooth curve $E \to S$ with geometrically connected fibers of genus one together with a section $0 : S \to E$, is called an *elliptic curve*.

I'm somewhat (not super) familiar/comfortable with schemes, and I know enough to see that this is a mild generalization of the definition given in say, Silverman's books. The author later considers a moduli problem and writes:

> We consider the moduli problem which assigns to a base scheme $S$ over $\mathcal{O}_D$ the category $C_D^+(S)$ of pairs $(E, \iota)$, where
>
> (i) $E$ is an elliptic curve over $S$ with complex multiplication $\iota : \mathcal{O}_D \hookrightarrow \operatorname{End}(E)$,
>
> (ii) such that the induced map $$\operatorname{Lie}(\iota) : \mathcal{O}_D \to \operatorname{End}_{\mathcal{O}_S}(\operatorname{Lie} E) = \mathcal{O}_S$$
> coincides with the structure map $S \to \operatorname{Spec} \mathcal{O}_D$.

There are two pieces of notation I'm not familiar with here: one is the use of $\operatorname{Lie}$ - I'm not sure what $\operatorname{Lie}(\iota)$ and $\operatorname{Lie} E$ mean, and the other is $\mathcal{O}_S$ - here I suspect this is the structure sheaf for $S$, but I want to clarify that point.

Neither of the algebraic geometry books I have handy include $\operatorname{Lie}$ in their symbol indices, and I haven't had any luck searching online, so **would anyone be able to explain what this means, or point me to the right resource on the topic?**

Comment: Which paper? It would be a good idea to include it in the question with an [edit].

Comment: Presumably this is some kind of Lie algebra related construction. The Lie algebra of an elliptic curve (the ordinary kind over a field) is the tangent space to the curve at the identity. Since the curves here are actually families of elliptic curves, $\operatorname{Lie}(E)$ should be the relative version of this construction, i.e. consider the tangent bundle $T E$ which has rank $2$, pass to the rank $1$ subbundle of "vertical" tangent vectors (those in the kernel of the differential of the structure map $E \to S$, and finally (I think) pushforward this subbundle to $S$...

Comment: ...Complicating things (here is one place having a link to the paper might help) is that it's hard to tell here what role is being played by $D$.